# Why doesn't it work for me to sort by date using tablesort?

Tags: javascript, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using this small [tablesort](http://tristen.ca/tablesort/demo/) js library to sort a table. I'm trying to get it to sort by the date as per their instructions: `"Basic dates in dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy format. Years can be 4 digits. Days and Months can be 1 or 2 digits."`

I have no clue why, but it sure does not sort my table as i wish. I would like it to sort from the oldest date -> newest data, or if you invert it by clicking again on it, from the newest date to the oldest.

If you try my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6325/) and click on Date - you'll see that there will be three different sorts instead of just the two - one that is not wanted.

Could i perhaps use the `data-sort:'12345...(some number here)'` on the `<td>`?

Comment: The date column in the Fiddle is a text sort, not dates, in IE 9.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? :) @RobG

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that i'm just stupid and that you can just use `data-sort='010101'` on the `<td>`'s. :) Great tablesorter!

Comment: Why don't you write your own? It's not that tough.